# Upgradable contract function not accessible

Tags: proxy-contracts, contract-upgrading

We have deployed the smart contract with proxy and using that proxy we have tried to upgrade the contract with some new functions. The contract is compiling and deploying and the upgrade process is completed successfully.

On the other hand we have an APIs using nodejs to access the contract functions.
Using the API we are only able to interact with the functions in the first contract when we try to access the new functions which are added using upgrade contract are accessible through API but it gives error.

Do you have any suggestions regarding this?

I use onlyOwner function.

Error:

Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (error={"reason":"execution reverted","code":"UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT","method":"estimateGas","transaction":

Comment: Developers need more information to help. Post as much as you can from the contract and the related nodejs code. Other questions: which type of proxy and pattern are you using? are you using OpenZeppelin contracts. have you tried to call the method using remix, have you tried to increase the gas limit? can you test the contract on a forked mainnet?.